# first column copy under empty line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

Salam
Following is the required output:

```
    RXOTG-136        VENEN6               0
                     VENEN6               1
                     VENEN7               0
                     VENEN7               1
    RXOTG-137        TIVIK6               0
                     TIVIK6               1
    RXOTG-138        KESTA1               0
                     KESTA1               1
                     KESTA2               0
                     KESTA2               1
                     KESTA3               0
                     KESTA3               1
    RXOTG-139        KESTA4               0
                     KESTA4               1
```

For which i used following command

```
    awk 'NF==1{a=$1; next}{ print val}'
```

but the output I am getting is

```
    RXOTG-136        VENEN6               0  
    RXOTG-136        VENEN6               1  
    RXOTG-136        VENEN7               0  
    RXOTG-136        VENEN7               1  
    RXOTG-137        TIVIK6               0  
    RXOTG-137        TIVIK6               1  
    RXOTG-138        KESTA1               0  
    RXOTG-138        KESTA1               1  
    RXOTG-138        KESTA2               0  
    RXOTG-138        KESTA2               1  
    RXOTG-138        KESTA3               0  
    RXOTG-138        KESTA3               1  
    RXOTG-139        KESTA4               0  
    RXOTG-139        KESTA4               1
```

Comment: what is the issue and what is your expected output?

Comment: Your question reads like "my script is `print 17` and it outputs `5` but it should output `23`" . How are we supposed to help you debug a script that doesn't do what you say it does (the awk script you posted will not output anything at all) and with no input to show where the output comes from?

Answer (score 2):

```
 awk 'NF==3{a=$1} NF==2{$1=a OFS $1} 1' file
```

- you need to store the first field somewhere
- 1 is for printing every line
- the format will change due to reassignment of $1~$3 thus you can use `column -t` to format it

  `awk 'NF==3{a=$1} NF==2{$1=a OFS $1} 1' file | column -t`

Answer (score 0):

Following simple `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '!/^ /{val=$1} /^ /{$1=val OFS $1} 1'  Input_file | column -t
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '1h;1b;s/^/\n/;G;:a;/\n\s(.*\n)(.)(.*\S+\s+\S+$)/s//\2\n\1\3/;ta;s/\n//;s/\n.*//;h' file
```

Print the first line after making a copy in the hold space. For all subsequent lines, prepend a newline and append the previous line. Copy a character at a time from the previous line to the front of the current line until either there are no more spaces at the front of the current line or there are only two fields in the previous line. Remove the first introduced newline and remove the remains of the previous line. Copy the current line to the hold space, ready for the next time and print the current line.